# Increment 2 class name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 list in my HTML. In both cases the list item star with a word and end with an increment number.

What I need is to change something in the items on the second list when I hover on the list one. Let me explain with an example:

When hover item-1 >> togleClass other-item-1
When hover item-2 >> togleClass other-item-2

My code at the moment is:

```
<ul class="first-list">
    <li class="link-0" title="eleme=www, elemnt2=33">link 01</li>
    <li class="link-1">link 02</li>
    <li class="link-2">link 03</li>
</ul>

<ul class="second-list">
    <li class="element-0">appartment-01</li>
    <li class="element-1">appartment-02</li>
    <li class="element-2">appartment-03</li>
</ul>
```

I know I can do something like

```
$('.link-0').hover(function(){$('.element-0').toggleClass('active'); });
```

But I don't want to repeat code the  wrote this:

```
$(function () {
        for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            $('.link-'+ x).hover(function(){
                $('.element-'+ x).toggleClass('active');
                    });
        }
    });
```

I know I can use a default class or li selector, but I need to use incremental class because when I hover link-1 I want to show .element-1

This is not working and I don't know what I'm missing here.

Could anyone help me?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

*Do not use incremental class or id attributes*. They are an anti-pattern which lead to needlessly complex code which is hard to maintain - as you've discovered in the JS sample you posted.

A much better approach given your requirements is to use the class on the `ul`, then relate the `li` elements by index, like this:

```js
$('.first-list li').hover(function() {
  $('.second-list li').eq($(this).index()).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="first-list">
  <li title="eleme=www, elemnt2=33">link 01</li>
  <li>link 02</li>
  <li>link 03</li>
</ul>

<ul class="second-list">
  <li>appartment-01</li>
  <li>appartment-02</li>
  <li>appartment-03</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory but that was my mistake to not explain that I need a different behavior for each element.

Comment: @Arol what's the different behaviour?

Comment: Elements is a list of images with z-index 0
What I need is when you are hover .link-0 change the z-index on element-1, when you are hover link-1 change z-index on element-1... and to the infinite

Comment: This pattern will work fine for that; set the `z-index` in the `.active` CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a common class for this:

```
<ul class="first-list">
    <li class="link-0 dummy-class" title="eleme=www, elemnt2=33">link 01</li>
        <ul class="second-list">
            <li class="element-0">appartment-01</li>
        </ul>
    <li class="link-1 dummy-class">link 02</li>
        <ul class="second-list">
            <li class="element-1">appartment-02</li>
        </ul>
    <li class="link-2 dummy-class">link 03</li>
        <ul class="second-list">
            <li class="element-0">appartment-03</li>
        </ul>
</ul>


$('.dummy-class').hover(function(){$(this).find('ul').show(); });
```

this way you don't need any incremental id or class

Comment: Thanks but I need to create a different behavior for each element

Comment: please then explain what is your expected result.

Comment: I've edited my question because I forgot to explain an important part of the issue

Comment: what about nesting the second ul into the first one? Then it is easy to select the right one with .find() and you trigger to see always the right one

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that because the development is more complex than the example :(